# Why is Button its own class in Android?

Tags: android, button, view

I'm new to Android and I noticed that the `Button` class extends `TextView` and `View` without overriding any methods or adding new ones. So why did they create it? We could use `View` objects without casting, and implement `onClickListener`.

Comment: I guess for ease-of-use/readability of the SDK. Everyone understands what a Button is. "Clickable TextView" doesn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: This is about the design of the classes, not how to press buttons or type in text boxes as an Android device user, so I'm reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Button` is-a `TextView`.

It has constructors that set `com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle` as the default style to the parent `TextView` ([source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Button.java)).

So you can think of `Button` as a `TextView` with overridden default style. Other than that, there's no practical difference.